# truncate table ? failing in execute SQL task

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

"truncate table ?" statement (without double quotes) failing in execute SQL task. 
i have set result set to "none", used a input parameter to pass the table name.

Comment: and it says the below error: 

 "Parameter name is unrecognized.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly. Task failed: Truncate table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use the parameter placeholder `?` in the TABLE or FROM clause.
Instead, build your SQL statement in a variable.

Varible Sqlstatement

```
EvaluateAsExpression: True 

Expression:

"TRUNCATE TABLE " + [User::tableName]
```

Then have the Execute SQL Task use that variable.

[image]

More information can be found [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/de1e4195-cd72-4b16-b196-9c1203df2565/execute-sql-task-executing-the-query-create-table-userfilename-failed?forum=sqlintegrationservices).